# How to call different setter methods dynamically based on the input data order/name in java?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-poi

I have about 20 variables in my class. I need to read an excel sheet and then get the data accordingly and set it in the DTO class depending on the name of the variables. 
Except 2, all variables are string. Those 2 are numeric.
Now i will get the single row from excel, next i have to get each cell's content and call the setter method explicitly based on the order of the data/index of the cell. Is there any way to automate this?
I mean any way to call a particular method for particular index? Can we define its relationship in an array somewhere and relate them?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumptions

1. Assuming 3, rather than 20 variables.
2. Assuming your excel sheet contains these columns:

   - column 1 = name
   - column 2 = street
   - column 3 = number.
3. Assuming the below is that class of yours:

   package com.johanw.stackoverflow.dynamicinit;

   public class MyObjectImpl {
       private String name;
       private String street;
       private int number;

   ```
   public MyObjectImpl() {
   }

   public MyObjectImpl(String name, String street, int number) {
       this.name = name;
       this.street = street;
       this.number = number;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getStreet() {
       return street;
   }

   public void setStreet(String street) {
       this.street = street;
   }

   public int getNumber() {
       return number;
   }

   public void setNumber(int number) {
       this.number = number;
   }

   public void setNumberAsString(String number) {
       this.number = Integer.valueOf(number);
   }
   ```

   }

---

Two different solutions spring to mind.

## Solution 1

1. The first solution would be using reflection and a list of method names ordered in the order you want to initialise your object, as shown in the below code...

   package com.johanw.stackoverflow.dynamicinit;

   import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
   import java.lang.reflect.Method;

   public class PopulateObjects2 {
       interface InitialiseFieldAction {
           void initialise(MyObjectImpl object, String value);
       }

   ```
   private static String[] initMethods = {
           "setName", "setStreet", "setNumberAsString"
   };

   private static Method getMethod(int index) throws NoSuchMethodException {
       if ((index < 0) || (index > initMethods.length - 1)) return null;
       Class clazz = MyObjectImpl.class;
       return clazz.getMethod(initMethods[index], String.class);
   }

   public static MyObjectImpl retrieveWithValues(String[] values) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
       if (values.length != initMethods.length) return null;   // Handle the fact you don't have the same amount of initialisations as the amount of fields
       MyObjectImpl o = new MyObjectImpl();
       for (int i = 0; i < initMethods.length; i++) {
           Method m = getMethod(i);
           m.invoke(o, values[i]);
       }
       return o;
   }
   ```

   }

## Solution 2

The second solution is to use the below pattern, using a list of InitialiseFieldAction implementations. Please note, in solution 2, I do no use the setNumberAsString method, but convert the string to numerical in the implementation of the InitialiseFieldAction.

```
package com.johanw.stackoverflow.dynamicinit;

public class PopulateObjects1 {

    interface InitialiseFieldAction {
        void initialise(MyObjectImpl object, String value);
    }

    private static InitialiseFieldAction[] initActions = new InitialiseFieldAction[] {
            new InitialiseFieldAction() { public void initialise(MyObjectImpl o, String value) { o.setName(value);} },
            new InitialiseFieldAction() { public void initialise(MyObjectImpl o, String value) { o.setStreet(value);} },
            new InitialiseFieldAction() { public void initialise(MyObjectImpl o, String value) { o.setNumber(Integer.valueOf(value));} },
    };

    public static MyObjectImpl retrieveWithValues(String[] values) {
        if (values.length != initActions.length) return null;   // Handle the fact you don't have the same amount of initialisations as the amount of fields
        MyObjectImpl o = new MyObjectImpl();
        for (int i = 0; i < initActions.length; i++) {
            initActions[i].initialise(o, values[i]);
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

---

## Usage

- For each row in your sheet, create an array of strings representing the values per column, from left to right.
- Then call PopulateObjects1/2.retrieveWithValues(that array).
- It'll return the object initialised with that array, as dynamically configured with initActions. In this case, InitialiseFieldAction implementation.

---

## Test

I've added the below unit test which allows to a) test b) understand how to use the code.

```
package com.johanw.stackoverflow.dynamicinit.init;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PopulateObjects {
    private String[] exampleRow = { "name", "street", "10"};

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        MyObjectImpl o = PopulateObjects1.retrieveWithValues(exampleRow);
        Assert.assertTrue(o.getName().equals("name"));
        Assert.assertTrue(o.getStreet().equals("street"));
        Assert.assertTrue(o.getNumber() == 10);
        System.out.println(o);
    }

    @Test
    public void method2() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        MyObjectImpl o = PopulateObjects2.retrieveWithValues(exampleRow);
        Assert.assertTrue(o.getName().equals("name"));
        Assert.assertTrue(o.getStreet().equals("street"));
        Assert.assertTrue(o.getNumber() == 10);
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

---

## Recommondation

I recommend to use the second method, i.e. not using reflection. However, you might have reasons to want to be able to use reflection in case the columns aren't fixed and you would retrieve these values from some configuration or from spreadsheet's header.

---

## Code

The code / project below is available at https://github.com/johanwitters/stackoverflow-dynamicinit

---

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For `MyObjectImpl`, see [answer of @johan-witter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065497/1649029)s.

## Solution 1: constructor accepting array

Just create a constructor that accepts the array with values. You will have to list all mappings between field number and setting, but you will have to do something similar in all solutions.

```
public MyObjectImpl(String[] values) {
    this.name = values[0];
    this.street = values[1];
    this.number = Integer.valueOf(values[0]);
    // ...
}
```

## Solution 2: define map with mapper function

Somewhat similar to solution 2 of @johan-witters, but uses just standard Java *Functional interfaces* and *Method references* which make it somewhat more compact.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] values = { /* data from file */};

    Map<Integer, BiConsumer<MyObjectImpl, String>> mappers = new HashMap<>();
    mappers.put(0, MyObjectImpl::setName);
    mappers.put(1, MyObjectImpl::setStreet);
    mappers.put(2, asInt(MyObjectImpl::setNumber));
    // ...

    MyObjectImpl obj = retrieveWithValues(values, mappers);

}

private static BiConsumer<MyObjectImpl, String> asInt(BiConsumer<MyObjectImpl, Integer> intConsumer) {
    return (obj, i) ->  intConsumer.accept(obj, Integer.valueOf(i));
}

private static MyObjectImpl retrieveWithValues(String[] values, Map<Integer, BiConsumer<MyObjectImpl, String>> mappers) {
    if (values.length != mappers.size()) {
        return null;
    }
    MyObjectImpl obj = new MyObjectImpl();
    for (int i = 0; i < mappers.size(); i++) {
        mappers.get(i).accept(obj, values[i]);
    }
    return obj;
}
```